# How to solve equations with two logarithmic terms?

Tags: logarithms

Once again I return with questions about logarithms. This time I am having trouble with solving equations of the following form:

$a\cdot \log(t)^{Q} - b\cdot \log(t)^{Z} = R $

I cannot figure out how to solve this equation for $t$. What I do know is the following: taking the exponential on both sides results in

$\exp(a\cdot \log(t)^{Q})  = \exp(R+ b\cdot \log(t)^{Z}) $
$\iff$
$\exp(a\cdot \log(t)^{Q})  = e^{R}\cdot e^{ b\cdot \log(t)^{Z}}.$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The  Q and Z are outside the logarithm?

Comment: Do you mean $log_{Q}(t)$?

Comment: I mean the logs are to the power Q and Z respectively, outside yes

Comment: Your issue is not solving with a logarithm. Just state that $u=\log t$ and see what is going on.

Comment: Yes exactly that, but then its not solvable right?

Comment: You are trying to solve $\alpha x^n+\beta x^m=1$

Comment: Can you give some more details about $a,b$. Are these integers? Are they coprimes?

Comment: They are sadly just real numbers nothing special.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "most" you can do is to define $x = \log(t)^Q$, then your equation is

$x = \frac{b}{a} x^{\frac{Z}{Q}} + \frac{R}{a}$

That's it, you want the solution to

$x = \alpha x^{\beta} + \gamma$

Sadly, the solution to this equation cannot be written in term of usual functions.

But you can calculate its approximate value for specific values of $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$